# "NoSuchElementException" Switching focus from popup to background

Tags: c#, html, selenium, dom

I have a code that checks for an element first before proceeding with taking a screenshot of the page, it won't stop the run but it will throw a runtime exception if the element is not found.

My problem is that it is always throwing an exception no matter what element I use, I'm thinking that it's because the driver is focusing on the pop up instead of the actual page, that's why it's not getting the element from the background.

So I guess what I need is to revert the focus back to the main page before going back to the popup, any idea how to do this?

**Code to check for elements:**

```
                //Open bi6 Report - Payroll Dashboard
                ieDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(appConfig["Bi6Page"]);
                Thread.Sleep(45000);
                wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
                try
                {
                    IWebElement bi6_reportHolder = ieDriver.FindElement(By.Id("reportContainer")); //change
                    //Check if pop-up is present
                    location = appConfig["SaveScreenShotLocation"] + "bi6_ScreenShot.png";
                    screenshotLocations.Add(location);
                    CheckPopUpAndTakeScreenShot(ieDriver, executor, location);

                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error while opening bi6 Report");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
```

**Function to close popups and take a screenshot:**

```
 public static void CheckPopUpAndTakeScreenShot(IWebDriver ieDriver, IJavaScriptExecutor executor, string location)
        {
            bool popupPresent = true;

            try
            {
                IWebElement popUpModal = ieDriver.FindElement(By.Id("issue-protocol-notice-modal"));
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                if (e.Message == @"Unable to find element with css selector == #issue\-protocol\-notice\-modal")//No Popup 
                    popupPresent = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (popupPresent)
                {
                    //Close Pop-up
                    IWebElement popUpDiv = ieDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("button-cancel"));
                    executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", popUpDiv);
                }
                //ORIGINAL SCREENSHOT
                Screenshot screenShot = ((ITakesScreenshot)ieDriver).GetScreenshot();
                screenShot.SaveAsFile(location, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);


            }
        }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: @mjwills  IWebElement bi8_reportHolder = ieDriver.FindElement(By.Id("grid-wrap"));

Comment: Spoiler alert - the ID almost certainly isn't there. Either a) it isn't there b) it isn't there yet (i.e. loaded via JS etc) c) it is looking at the wrong window.

Comment: @mjwills Sorry, I think you're right. It was just odd that I sometimes don't see the exceptions for the other two and that it always proceeds with the next functions, so I just assumed that they're working. I think what's happening is its focusing on the pop up that's why it can't see the elements in the background. It's still a mystery to me though why the code proceeds even after encountering the exception.